# How can I mix different fonts in a RichTextBox, a TextBox or a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

Could anyone help me with this problem? I have four sentences that have to be displayed in different fonts. I am using windows forms.

Example: "Once you have completed the test, you will be returned to
          this screen. *Note: you can take the test only one time*"
         How do I make this second sentence be a different font?

I tried this, but it only works for one sentence. Not the way to go:

```
Dim BO As New Font("Cambria", 12, FontStyle.Bold) ' Bold
TextBox2.Font = BO
TextBox2.Text = "Sentence"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `RichTextBox`, you can use the [.SelectionFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx) property.

Something like this should do the trick;

```
TextBox2.Selectionstart = TextBox2.Find("Note;")
TextBox2.SelectionFont = New Font(TextBox2.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
```

Comment: Yes, but with it, there is no way to hide the cursor

Comment: To clarify myself, when using richtext box, you can't hide the cursor. I can hide it temporarily but then if you click in the text, it appears again.